# How to publish a closed source library to jCenter?

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

Is it possible to publish a private SDK to jCenter?
I already set up everything and the upload to bintray works fine, however I want to publish the .aar library but not the java docs and the java source.

I've seen some libraries upload an empty javadoc.jar and sources.jar, how do I achieve this with gradle?

Comment: if you found an answer to this please share

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can't.
JCenter only accepts OSS libraries.
You're more than welcome to use your own repository for it. The consumers will need to add your repository in the `repositories` block of their build, but otherwise it will work exactly the same.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Hey JBaruch, I actually would like to publish a library that is OSS - but would like to do so manually for now.  I registered, but see no option of where I would add a jar/library/etc.

Comment: [Upload files to Bintray](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_howdoiuploadmystufftobintray.html). And I think that deserves a question of its own, since has nothing to do with the question we are commenting on.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961175) suggests that premium organizations can still link their private repo to JCenter even if they're not OSS. Is that correct?