# Bintray link to jcenter missing

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I would like to ask about bintray link to jcenter. Apparently I can't link to jcenter anymore as the button 'linked to jcenter' is missing. I had created new package(under maven repository). I had no issues linking to jcenter when I was testing with one account during 2016 december and the 'linked to jcenter' button is there but now when I try with new account the button is missing. What makes this happens? When I was trying in 2016, I just need to create maven repository and the 'linked to jcenter' button should be there already.
Thanks for advance for anyone helping me.
[Linked to jcenter button missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATdvi.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Add To JCenter" is not enabled for Enterprise Trial users. You need to be OSS or Premium organization/user in order to link your packages to JCenter.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I see, because when I was trying as free users in 2016 December it still works. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: One more thing. Even if you have Admin role in an account of your Company you will not be able to use linking. It requires Owner role.

Comment: So Do i have to go premium to link library to JCeneter?

Comment: @Shvet, **no**, you can link with OSS account, please read the preconditions.

Comment: @Royg Thanks I got it, my client has activated free trial, so i coudnt find it.