# there is no "add to jcenter" button in "https://bintray.com"

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I want to upload a library to jcenter, now I have upload it into "https://bintray.com", but there is no "add to jcenter" button in "Linked to" module, I have read the document and compared it with other person's, but can't found out the reason. the package link [click here](https://bintray.com/dfqin21/study/grantor)

> Before you can include your package in JCenter, the following
>   requirements must be met: 1)The package must be in a Maven repository
>   and must contain Maven sources. 2)The path of the files (entered in the
>   Upload Files form of the Version page) must conform to Maven standards
>   (the Group ID and Artifact ID combination must be unique, etc.; for
>   more information about Maven standards, consult the appropriate Maven
>   documentation) 3)Every version within the package that includes files
>   must also include a valid POM file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bintray link to jcenter missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953886/bintray-link-to-jcenter-missing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Add To JCenter" is not enabled for Enterprise Trial users. You need to be OSS or Premium organization/user in order to link your packages to JCenter.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

Comment: Also you need to be an Owner, not Admin in order to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that if you running a **trial** account, you won't see this option as linking your package to jcenter is **permanent**.