# Unable to add my library to JCenter

Tags: android, jcenter

Hi I am working on one library just for my learning purpose. I am trying to publish it on JCenter. I have followed all the steps of this tutorial https://medium.com/@daniellevass/how-to-publish-your-android-studio-library-to-jcenter-5384172c4739#.fdsjj7qku

I am unable to add to JCenter my library, there is no text of "Add to JCenter" is being shown to me. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem ?

Expected state:

[image: Expected state]

Current state:

[image: Current state]

Comment: post your library link..

Comment: try this dependencies {
    compile 'com.tsengvn:typekit:1.0.1'
}

Comment: example coder here... https://github.com/tsengvn/Typekit?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1957

Comment: @Javacoder You didn't get my question. I have different question! Read it please again

Comment: The error you are getting is because it is not in JCenter, as you pointed. Can you show the full screen of your Bintray page? You probably didn't created this project with the "Maven" type...

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira Open this https://bintray.com/tgmcians/Android-Typekit

Comment: Even I was trying to publish one library for my learning. I can able to make it as a library using the same tutorial from medium. But i was unable to find publish to jcenter option as well.

Comment: from my learning you can only compile 'com.nagarro.typekit:android-typekit:1.0' use this to add your library only when it is published to jcenter and. I am sure very sure that your library is only availble in Maven not in jcenter

Comment: @HourGlass Hmm How I can link it to JCenter ?

Comment: No idea man I am still looking for answers. @Williams

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41961175/7101554. Do you have an Enterprise trial account? This might be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to link your library if you are using a Trial account, as linking to jcenter is permanent...

Many people have this problem, as you can see here:

[Bintray link to jcenter missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953886/bintray-link-to-jcenter-missing/41961175#41961175)

And here:

[there is no "add to jcenter" button in "https://bintray.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035918/there-is-no-add-to-jcenter-button-in-https-bintray-com)

But not to worry... Just create a OSS account and you will be able to link your Open Source libraries.