# artifact or version defined in the pom file do not match

Tags: java, android, maven, jcenter

I made android open source library and try upload in `bintray`.for this i follow [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) toturial but in last step for upload project i get this error :

> Could not upload to
>   'https://api.bintray.com/content/saman/PersianDate/PersianDate/0.0.2/com/github/samanzamani/persiandate/persiandate/0.0.2/persiandate-0.0.2.pom':
>   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to upload files: Maven group,
>   artifact or version defined in the pom file do not match the file path
>   'com/github/samanzamani/persiandate/persiandate/0.0.2/persiandate-0.0.2.pom']

buld

install.gradle file :

```
ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'PersianDate'
    bintrayName = 'PersianDate'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.samanzamani.persiandate'
    libraryName = 'PersianDate'
    artifact = 'PersianDate'

    libraryDescription = 'A simple jalali date converter'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/samanzamani/PersianDate'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/samanzamani/PersianDate.git'

    libraryVersion = '0.0.2'

    developerId = 'zamani'
    developerName = 'Saman Zamani'
    developerEmail = 'saman.zamani1@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
```

bintray.gradle file :

```
version = libraryVersion

if (project.hasProperty("android")) { // Android libraries
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }
} else { // Java libraries
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

// Bintray
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = bintrayRepo
        name = bintrayName
        userOrg=properties.getProperty("bintray.org")
        desc = libraryDescription
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = allLicenses
        publish = true
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
        version {
            desc = libraryDescription
            gpg {
                sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
                passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password")
                name = libraryVersion
                //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply from: 'install.gradle'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 2
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "Alfa"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

any idea..!?

Comment: You should check out : https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release

Comment: @reversiblean Awesome . that is simple way thanks. did you know how can publish my library to `jCenter` because i can't see `link to jcenter` in `bintray` project panel.

Comment: No idea. Are you a trial user?

Comment: yes for now i'm trial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035918/there-is-no-add-to-jcenter-button-in-https-bintray-com. You probably don't have to pay. Do some research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140223/discussion-between-reversiblean-and-saman).