# Link to JCentre button not present

Tags: repository, bintray, jcenter

This is unfamiliar to me - I am not used to distributing software in this way, but it seems like everything should be working, unless I have made a mistake.

On Bintray, I'm trying to release a thing I forked as I want to include it as a dependency in my lib and my app, instead of directly. It's also a learning thing, so feel free to educate me if appropriate.

I've uploaded everything correctly I believe, and unlike every other question I've seen - **I actually have signed up for an OSS account**, but still can't see the "Link to JCentre" button -

Did I do something wrong? Or has something changed?

I also am assuming I may have to wait for a while before I can link it.I can see my version badge and so on, but I want to access this via gradle. The section appears on my package information screen, but it says 0 links and there's no buttons.

Thanks guys!

Here is a link to my (EDIT: [now successfully updated]) [repository](https://bintray.com/systemecks/system-ecks). It is a fork of [Galgo](https://github.com/inaka/galgo) to add support for Android M+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be enable to "Link to JCenter", your repository needs to be public and Maven type, you also can't be a trial user (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961175/3719024)).

The problem that you are facing is that your repository if `Generic` and not `Maven`.

You can check your repository type by navigating to your **repository edit page**, you'll find the `Type` field (which can't be edited). It should say `Maven`.
You can also check the *Owned Repositories* from the **organization profile page**. The text in parenthesis states the repository type.

Comment: Hey, I actually have signed up for an OSS account, I don't think it is a maven type, although I'm not sure what you mean. I can see that some maven files were generated, but I haven't done any maven. Here is the [link](https://dl.bintray.com/systemecks/systemecks)

Comment: Go to your repository edit page, there is a field called `Type`, yours probably says `Generic` and not `Maven`.     You can also check the `Owned Repositories` from the organization profile page, in parenthesis is the repository type.

Comment: Nice one, that looks to be it - it actually won't let me edit the field at the moment, but in about 30 mins I will just recreate the repository and package - I wasn't sure what that was about when I was setting up now that I think about it! Could you update your answer to include that and I'll accept it?